# Modified dining philosophers with semaphores

Tags: semaphore, dining-philosopher

In this modified version of the dining philosophers problem, a philosopher may use *any* of the forks available, not just those on his left and right. Given the following solution to the original problem using semaphores

```
system DINING_PHILOSOPHERS

VAR me:    semaphore, initially 1;                    /* for mutual exclusion */ 

s[5]:  semaphore s[5], initially 0;               /* for synchronization */ 

pflag[5]: {THINK, HUNGRY, EAT}, initially THINK;  /* philosopher flag
*/


procedure philosopher(i)   {
    while TRUE do
     {
       THINKING;
       take_chopsticks(i);
       EATING;
       drop_chopsticks(i);
     }   }

procedure take_chopsticks(i)   {
    DOWN(me);               /* critical section */
    pflag[i] := HUNGRY;
    test[i];
    UP(me);                 /* end critical section */
    DOWN(s[i])              /* Eat if enabled */    }

void test(i)            /* Let phil[i] eat, if waiting */   {
    if ( pflag[i] == HUNGRY
      && pflag[i-1] != EAT
      && pflag[i+1] != EAT)
       then
        {
          pflag[i] := EAT;
          UP(s[i])
         }
    }

void drop_chopsticks(int i)   {
    DOWN(me);                /* critical section */
    test(i-1);               /* Let phil. on left eat if possible */
    test(i+1);               /* Let phil. on rght eat if possible */
    UP(me);                  /* up critical section */    }
```

So I wish to find a simple edit to the pseudo-code above that will allow for a philosopher to eat using *any* 2 of the 5 forks. My first thought is I can remove the logic in `test` and `drop_chopsticks` that checks whether, once I am done eating, my neighbors can now eat..or can I? This variation of the problem does not seem like it would complicate it much but I am stuck on how exactly to implement this. Note that it must still use semaphores and avoid starvation/deadlock.

Comment: I believe you can limit the number of semaphores you need to be using?